# @Html.TextBoxFor() generates empty textbox when corresponding property has a value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a default ASP.NET MVC 5 project.

I have added a FullName property to the user:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Added this property to the viewmodel as well:

```
public class ManageUserViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And display a textbox on a view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FullName)
```

It works well, I can set the FullName of the user. I have only one problem: if the user already has a FullName set, the textbox is still empty. How can I make it have to actual value of FullName property?

**EDIT:**

This is the controller which displays the view with the textbox:

```
    public ActionResult Manage(ManageMessageId? message)
    {
        ViewBag.StatusMessage =
            message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
            : message == ManageMessageId.ChangeDetailsSuccess ? "Your details have been changed."
            : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
            : message == ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess ? "The external login was removed."
            : message == ManageMessageId.Error ? "An error has occurred."
            : "";
        ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = HasPassword();
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Do you map it properly in the controller when returning the view? You have to grab the `FullName` from the `ApplicationUser` and put it in the view model.

Comment: set a breakpoint in the .cshtml and check the FullName property of the Model

Comment: @JLe: I'm afraid I don't. How can I do that? I have added the controller method which returns the view which has the textbox.

Comment: @thefiloe: after setting the breakpoint, how can I access the model while debugging the cshtml?

Comment: Just use the DirectInput-Window and type Model.FullName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to 1) get the `ApplicationUser` you're looking for, and 2) bind the property to the view model.

```
public ActionResult Manage(ManageMessageId? message)
{
    ViewBag.StatusMessage =
        message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
        : message == ManageMessageId.ChangeDetailsSuccess ? "Your details have been changed."
        : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
        : message == ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess ? "The external login was removed."
        : message == ManageMessageId.Error ? "An error has occurred."
        : "";
    ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = HasPassword();
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");

    // Get the currently logged on user
    var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

    // Copy the value of FullName to the view model
    var vm = new ManageUserViewModel {
        FullName = user.FullName
    };
    return View(vm);
}
```